# Laravel eloquent update one-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4

in laravel, i have set up the one to many relationship properly and i can save the relationship by using saveMany function.

```
$post->comment()->saveMany($array);
```

The problem is:

How can Laravel remove the unused comment automatically and only store the latest comment to the database?

For example.
first time,

```
ID 1 Post has ID 1, ID2, ID 3 comment.
```

However, when I update the relationship later,

```
ID 1 Post only has ID 2, ID 3 comment
```

how can laravel remove the `ID 1 comments` automatically ? and just leave `ID 2, 3` in the table?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With saveMany() you attach new entities and setting the foreign key to the parent automatically (Setting `$comment->post_id = $post->id;` when storing them). This is just for attaching them, because you are stating that the comment is always related to the post. The one-to-many defines that your Post has many comments and a comment belongs to the post, defined by the post_id in the comment.

Unless you want to have comments unrelated to posts, which makes no sense, I would say you should not unset the post_id from comments, but just delete the comment if you want to get rid of them.
However if you do, try `$comment->dissociate()`, which unsets the parent key. It's like using `detach()` on many to many.

Comment: The problem is laravel does not remove the unrelated comments when I use save many again. The unrelated comments still keeping in the database with the parent key, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: `saveMany()` only adds new items, it does not remove them. For unsetting the parent use @zub0r 's example, or use `$comment->dissociate()` there like i said above. If you want to remove them all the way instead of unsetting the relation and saving it, just call `$comment->delete();` in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [detach()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models) method like for many-to-many relations, but you can do

```
// detach old first
$post->comment()->get()->each(function($comment) use ($array){        
    if (!in_array($comment, $array)) 
    // if (!$array->contains($comment)) in case of collection
    {
        $comment->post_id = null;
        $comment->save();
    }        
});

// attach new ones
$post->comment()->saveMany($array);
```

Hope this helps.